# How can I use several data sets in Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have a question in regards to Shiny. I have four data sets and depending on the user's input, I want to use one of the four data sets for the computations.
I tried using an if-statement, but it doesn't work. I also tried using a reactive expression, but could not make that work. Is it technically possible what I want to do? And if so, how?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
    theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),  

    titlePanel("Some Data"),

    sidebarLayout(

      sidebarPanel(
            
            checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h3("Choose your tea brand:"), 
                               choices = list("Solar" = 1, 
                                              "Green" = 2, 
                                              "Cat" = 3, 
                                              "Conservation" = 4)),

           selectInput("tea", "Choose your tea:", c("Green Tea", "Black Tea", "Blue Tea")
            
        ),

        mainPanel(
        
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("Titel",
              
            h4("Subtitel"),
            verbatimTextOutput("demographicsTable"),
            
            h4("Subtitel"),
            tableOutput("nbhsizeTable"),
            ))))

server <- function(input, output) {

      if(input$checkGroup == "Solar"){
        Data <- read.csv("SolarData.csv")
      } else if(input$checkGroup == "Green"){
        Data <- read.csv("GreenData.csv")
      } else if(input$checkGroup == "Conservation"){
        Data <- read.csv("ConservationData.csv")
      } else if(input$checkGroup == "Cat"){
        Data <- read.csv("CatData.csv")
      }

  output$demographicsTable <- renderPrint({
              
      dat <- Data %>% filter(grepl(input$tea, cookies))  
        
        ### age
        age <- summary(dat$age)
        
        ### gender
        gender <- table(dat$gender)
        
        dat <- list(Age = c(age[1], age[4], age[6]), 
                    Gender = gender)
        dat

    })
    
    output$nbhsizeTable <- renderTable({
              
        dat <- Data %>% filter(grepl(input$tea, cookies))
        
        table(dat$size_of_teacup)

    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things going on here.

First, I think the biggest piece is that the `input$checkGroup` returns the values in the selection list, not the labels/names displayed to the user. It also returns this value as a string, i.e. when the user selects "Solar", the server will see an input value of "1".

Second, your `Data` variable needs to be a reactive. Right now your if/else statement will be executed at launch and never again. Since you don't specify an initial selection, the input value will be `NULL` not matching any of the conditional statements, and no value will be assigned to `Data`.

I would do something along the lines of this. Load your data sets into a static list (this will prevent reads from disk every time the user adds/removes checks)

```
teaData <- list(
  read.csv("SolarData.csv"),
  read.csv("GreenData.csv"),
  read.csv("CatData.csv"),
  read.csv("ConservationData.csv")
)
```

Then create a reactive that subsets this list by coercing the input values and combines them based on selections

```
Data <- reactive({
  dplyr::bind_rows(teaData[as.integer(input$checkGroup)])
})
```

I can't really test the solution without sample data, but I think the solution is straightforward enough this should work.

Comment: Ok, thanks! This works for the data set input. However, I have made the select input conditional on the checkbox input, and that one does not work now.

Comment: If I understand what you did, you would need an observer that updates the select input whenever the checkbox group changes. Something along the lines of (need to add `session` to your server function arguments) `observeEvent(Data, updateSelectInput(session, "tea", choices = <<new choices>>))`